# Getting EndpointNotFoundException: There was no channel actively listening in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, wcf-configuration

I have created a WCF multiservice with two interfaces, i'm trying to export two endpoints one for each service.
Here below you can see the two endpoints:

```xml
<service behaviorConfiguration="SAGBService_Behavior" name="SAGBService.SAGBService">
    <endpoint address="basic" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="SAGBService.ICalculeLactation" />
    <endpoint address="basic1" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="SAGBService.ISAGBService" />
  </service>
```

when i try to call the service i have and error telling me that the endpoint is not found.

> [EndpointNotFoundException]: There was no channel actively listening
>   at 'http://localhost:3197/SAGBService.svc/GetRapportTrimestiel/0/0/0/20150401/20150430&#39;. This is
>   often caused by an incorrect address URI. Ensure that the address to
>   which the message is sent matches an address on which a service is
>   listening.

but when i remove the second endpoint, it works can access the functions on ICalculeLactation:

```xml
<service behaviorConfiguration="SAGBService_Behavior" name="SAGBService.SAGBService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="SAGBService.ICalculeLactation" />
  </service>
```

the problem is that i'm interested in the fuctions that are on 
ISAGBService

Comment: You have two endpoints for one service, try using them in separate services or possibly using the same contract for all of the functions.

Comment: Does ICalculeLactation really provide an interface for calculations relating to secretion of milk by mammary glands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the error says it: `This is often caused by an incorrect address URI`

Your endpoint has the address of "basic1", but the URL request does not include that address.
`http://localhost:3197/SAGBService.svc/GetRapportTrimestiel/0/0/0/20150401/20150430`

vs

`http://localhost:3197/SAGBService.svc/basic1/GetRapportTrimestiel/0/0/0/20150401/20150430`